# Clicking on a polygon-opening a page/link

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have a many polygons on my map serving through WMS from geoserver. I want to implement the task such that when the user clicks on a particular polygon , he should be directed to a html page about that polygon. Like if I click on my CSE Dept I should be directed to my cse dept home page.

Need help in achieving this...

I have followed http://lyceum.massgis.state.ma.us/wiki/doku.php?id=generate_imagemap as but when I try "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=IITKanpur:halls&styles=iitk_halllinks&bbox=80.226,26.504,80.235,26.512&width=512&height=455&srs=EPSG:4326&format=text/html" I am not getting anything.

My iitk_halllinks sld is :

`<Rule>
  <Name>href</Name>
  <PointSymbolizer><Graphic><Size>16</Size></Graphic></PointSymbolizer>
  <TextSymbolizer><Label><PropertyName>halls_link</PropertyName></Label></TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the i[magemap extension](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/geoserver/geoserver-2.1.0-imagemap-plugin.zip) and follow the the example http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/imagemap.html which allows you to request the map using text/html. This will provide the ability to click on a polygon

Answer (score 4):

Use this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html

But instead of doing this:

```
    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
            map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                "chicken", 
                map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                null,
                event.text,
                null,
                true
            ));
        }
    }
```

replace the above for something like this:

```
eventListeners: {
    getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
        window.open("http://mydomain.com/polygoninfo.php?polygonid=" + event.feature.attributes.id, "window_name","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=650,height=650");
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for a single polgon, but I have multiple polygons in my layer

Comment: @user1795 > no, this works with one or N polygons. That's why the script is passing the id dynamically

Comment: @user: like simo said, this will work with any amount of polygons. Just pass the polygon id in the URL on the click event (event.feature.attributes.id) and your polygoninfo.php page can query that ID for all of it's information.